# Sending keystroke to inactive window

Tags: autohotkey

I want to send a keystroke to chrome, but it only works while the window is active. I'd like this to work even when the window is in the background.

```
;begin
Pause
Loop {
ControlSend,,{escape}, Omegle - Google Chrome
Sleep 2650
}
F9::Pause
;end
```

Comment: Don't have a full example but you probably need to use PostMessage instead of ControlSend.  PostMessage can start a window by it's handle, whereas ControlSend is closer to emulating the user pressing a key - which relies on the currently focused window.

Answer (score 1):

To operate upon a control's HWND (window handle), leave the Control parameter blank and specify ahk_id %ControlHwnd% for the WinTitle parameter (this also works on hidden controls even when DetectHiddenWindows is Off). The HWND of a control is typically retrieved via ControlGet Hwnd, MouseGetPos, or DllCall.

From http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm

Comment: yeaaaaah I have no idea how to do that. The best I could come up with was:
ControlGet, ControlHwnd, Hwnd,,, Omegle - Google Chrome

ControlSend,,{escape}, ahk_id %ControlHwnd%

Comment: That should be it according to the docs. Any errors or just not working?

Comment: Just doesn't work. But it works fine when I actually tab INTO the window.

In other words, controlget is working (I think), but it's for whatever reason only working when I tab back into chrome.

Comment: Oh nvm it doesn't work. For whatever reason it doesn't loop now.

Comment: Maybe chrome doesn't accept the escape key at the global window level, maybe it needs to target a specific tab control or something like that. I'm not on windows right now so can't really test. Try to set a breakpoint and inspect the ControlHwnd variable and see if it's being grabbed correctly. Try it without the loop at first.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Omegle would change the window title sometimes.

Comment: Great. Also i think window title can be only a part of the title, so you don't need the full title just Omegle should work. You can probably find something that they don't change.

Comment: Oh no, the problem is that it doesn't work when chrome isn't active. I just figured out why it stopped working after a little while, while the window is active. 

Basically, right now the script just doesn't work when tabbed out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88142/discussion-between-felix-maxime-and-dinomix).